# Java scanner error without finishing the file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read a paragraph in java via Scanner class and printout the line. However, I encoutner a very strange issue. I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
        at Test.main(Test.java:10)
```

and the print before that is not the end of the file. The print stops at the first word on a specific line every time and there are 5-6 lines more in the file.

My code:

```
try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filename));
            for (int i = 1; i < 3801; i++){
                System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
            }
            scanner.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Can we see the file? Maybe not the whole thing if it's 3801 lines long, but just the problem line, and what comes after?

Comment: Issue was with the encoding, after adding UTF-8 it is working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following to determine the **end of file** instead of hardcoded integer.

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
}
```

Comment: That is what I was using before i changed it to a for loop so I can see if it throws any errors. Anyways, the problem was with the encoding. After adding UTF-8 as an encoder everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your scanner.nextLine() is in a for-loop.

It is recommended that you use a while-loop instead.

The condition of the while-loop should be scanner.hasNextLine() which basically translates to "While the scanner has another line ahead in the file, run the code inside the while-loop, otherwise stop the while-loop"

That way, if the scanner doesn't have any more lines to read, it simply stops the loop and continues with the rest of the code.

In your for-loop, you are forcing the scanner to keep reading the file even though it has no other lines to read.

The code should be:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("read.txt"));
      while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
             System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
        }
      scanner.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently java was confused by the encoding of the file and that is why it was crashing. After adding `"UTF-8"` in the scanner class now it read everything fine.

Comment: Was it a plain txt file?